# WPF progress bar update without dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am trying to show a progress bar on seperate window on a button click.
I dont want to use dispatcher,invoke function because I dont want user to do anything else until it completes.

So on button click im calling a function which is internally using delegate to call the function with the update.

```
void button click()
{
   classA.function(list);
}
```

Inside that classA

```
void function(list)
{
 foreach(list)
   calling the delegate function(ShowtProgress) to update the progress bar with current and max properties.
}
```

so my delegate function looks something like this:

```
private void ShowtProgress(ProgressReport importProgressReport)
{
            importProgressBar.UpdateProgressBar(importProgressReport.OverallProgress.TotalItems,importProgressReport.OverallProgress.ItemsProcessed);
            importProgressBar.ShowDialog();
}
```

As you can see that im passing how many are currently processed and total items to the progress bar updateProgressbar function to update the progress bar.

I have defined progress bar's minimum to 0.

But the problem is the moment it shows the showdialog(of progress bar) the first time when min = 0  and assume max = 1. it stays right there waiting for the user's input. Until I dont close the dialog the processing doesn't go further and when again this function is called the modal doesn't pop up or doesn't get updated with the latest value.

Do let me know, if I have missed anything.

Comment: It is waiting for user input because of the ShowDialog() call, use either the normal Show() (if importProgressBar wasn't visible) or just remove the line if it was already.

Comment: You should learn [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your questions properly already...

Comment: @H.B.:I would keep that in mind for the next time. Thnx for pointing out

Comment: Hi Roy, show() did the trick. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is waiting for user input because of the `ShowDialog()` call. Use either the normal `Show()` (if `importProgressBar` wasn't visible) or just remove the line if it was already.

Comment: Since Roy's seems to answer the question, I have copied it as a proper answer.